# In WordPress how do I set a text limit or break the text when it hits a certain length

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm new in WordPress and want to know how to set a text limit or break, so that when the text length reaches a certain number it doesn't continue in one line only and moves to the next line.

e.g. how do i make this text:

```
this is an example text for demonstrating line break
```

into this:

```
this is an example text for

demonstrating line break
```

Could you please help me to achieve the line breaks automatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php wordpwrap to achieve this:

```
<?php
$text = "Portez ce vieux whisky au juge blond qui fume.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

Will display:

```
Portez ce vieux<br />
whisky au juge<br />
blond qui fume.
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php